# Instantiate only certain objects within a prefab Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am making a level platformer, and want all coins to respawn when you fall down into the void. I currently have the entire level being deleted and reinstantiated using a prefab, but this is just not working for a variety of reasons. Obviously it's taxing, escpecially when bigger levels get involved, and now, I don't want certain elements to do that (get reinstantiated - or, for that matter - deleted), like heart containers. SO... my solution that I am pursuing in the moment is to just reinstantiate the coins, which seems easy, but I can't access them, since they are no longer there (the player has collected them). This means that I have to access them through being children of the level prefab. The levels are stored in a array, and I access them only when they need to be instantiated or deleted. I also use a variable called _currentlevel to store the current one. So any solution is very much accepted. You have no idea how grateful I will be.

Edit: Maybe doing something with childCount could work? Is childCountWithTag a thing? :)

Another Edit: All the coins have the layer "Coins" and tag "Coin", and are triggers (obviously). Also ignore the "-1" after in the Instantiation line. I assure you it's necessary

Video Clips: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZExAJrAedoaB45sJkgjoUMjMU65AiDv4/view?usp=sharing

(I want the coins to be instantiated, but not things like the heart, trees, or tiles.)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RyT1guCVnC7kF-Qzq0fb2L49SsJXMdNP/view?usp=sharing

Thanks! Code Below.

```
 if(Character.transform.position.y < -10)
 {
     playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
     Character.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
     Lives -= 1;
     Score = 0;
     PlayerController.Player.superJumps = 0;
     _currentLevel = Instantiate(levels[Level-1].transform.GetChild(0));
 }
```

Comment: That's not really how prefabs work. Instead, make a prefab of prefabs, and instantiate the "sub-prefabs" that you want.

Comment: Actually, it is how prefabs work. I'm sure of that, and it's still not possible even with your idea. You can't put prefabs within prefabs. And I don't want to download any software or whatever that could allow me to do that.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NestedPrefabs.html It's literally part of Unity. If you don't want to download software (like Unity) to make a Unity project - I wish you luck.

Comment: Give me a sec to look into it in my project.

Comment: Everything in Unity is built on the concept of a hierarchy. We do that on purpose. It's very rare to find a feature that doesn't take advantage of that.

Comment: Yep, sorry. *facepalms* I'm an idiot. I was thinking of something totally different. I already am, and need to instantiate those coins (which are prefabs within the level prefab) in their specific location, without having to put in the locations.

Comment: So, you want to instantiate a bunch of coins at predefined locations? Make a new prefab with a bunch of coin prefabs attached, and set their positions within that prefab. The transform should be part of the parent prefab. Shrug.

Comment: That seems like a lot more work than just instantiating only part of the prefab. I thought this was a simple solution that I wasn't aware of, but maybe not. I don't want to have two prefabs for every singe level. That gets messy really quick.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. You want to instantiate a prefab, but not say where it should be. So, that information either needs to be part of the prefab, or stored somewhere else. The system isn't magic.

Comment: Uploading another video just as an example. Give me a sec. Do you have discord or something? We could continue there? That would be great. Just quick, not long term or anything.

Comment: Why dont you just search for all children gameobjects name "coin" in your prefab, and instantiate them? you can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html or even https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html

Comment: Because I don't know when I instantiated all of them. But I'll try to dive deeper into that. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Instead of destroying and instantiating the coins at all you could simply keep them all in place, only disable them and when you need to "respawn" all coins simply have a central manager that knows and enables them all again

Comment: That's super smart, I'm going to use that method. Then the level - including coins will be destroyed when the next level is loaded. Thank you so much to all.